# SQLAlchemy: pass extra options into session.merge

Tags: sqlalchemy

In documentation on .**merge** is written :https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.merge that it is possible to pass extra options which lately will be applied into **session.get**. Is **session.get** documentation is written that is is possible to use **with_for_update** option https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.get.params.with_for_update

```py
place_model = type(place)
    try:
        async with session.begin_nested():
            place_merged = await session.merge(place, options={'with_for_update': True})
    except sa_exc.IntegrityError as err:
....
....
```

I have been trying to use it like this but got an exception  - *sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: ExecutionOption Core or ORM object expected, got 'with_for_update'.*

Question is  - how to add option **with_for_update** into session.merge correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a misunderstadning I think.

The [merge docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.merge.params.options) state:

> **options** –
> optional sequence of loader options which will be applied to the Session.get() method when the merge operation loads the existing version of the object from the database.

I believe this maps to the [options parameter](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.get.params.options) of `Session.get`:

> **options** – optional sequence of loader options which will be applied to the query, if one is emitted.

[with_for_update](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.get.params.with_for_update) is a separate parameter, it cannot be passed via `Session.merge`.